# Where do Baudhyana dharma sutras mention Ganapati?

Tags: identification-request, ganesha, dharma-shastras

According to [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kartikeya#Ancient) on Kartikeya-

> While the Baudhayana Dharmasutra mentions a householder's rite of passage that involves prayers to Skanda with his brother Ganapati (Ganesha) together.

Where is Ganesha mentioned in Baudhayana Dharma Sutras?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's there in Baudhayana Dharma Sutras 2.9.6. The Mantras are as follows:

> OM . I quench the Rudras. OM . I quench Rudra’s male attendants. OM . I quench Rudra’s female attendants.
>    7 OM . I quench Vighna. **OM . I quench Vinayaka. OM . I quench Vıra. OM . I quench Sthula. OM . I quench Varada. OM . I quench Hastimukha. OM . I quench Vakratunda. OM . I quench Ekadanta. OM . I quench Lambodara.*** OM . I quench Vighna’s male attendants. OM . I quench Vighna’s female attendants.
>   8 OM . I quench Sanatkumara. OM . **I quench Skanda.** OM . I quench Indra. OM . I quench Sastı. OM . **I quench Sanmukha. OM . I quench Jayanta. OM . I quench Visakha.** OM . I quench Maha sena. OM . **I quench Subrahmanya. OM . I quench Skanda’s male attendants. OM . I quench Skanda’s female attendants**.
>   9 OM . I quench Aditya. OM . I quench Soma. OM . I quench Angaraka. OM . I quench Budha.

**UPDATE:**

Updating the answer in reply to @sv's comment below.

[Here is the Dharma Sutra](http://www.hinduonline.co/vedicreserve/kalpa/dharma/baudhayana_dharma_sutra.pdf) in Sanskrit.

The Mantras are actually Tarpana Mantras (used for offering libations of water to various deities). In such Mantras either "Tarpayami" is present or "Tripyantam".

Here, in the text, Tarapayami is present and which they have translated as "I quench".

The Mantras for Ganesha and Skanda (and their allies) are present in **pp 28-29** of the Sanskrit PDF.

[image: Screenshot from Sanskrit PDF showing Ganesha and Skanda names from pages 28-29]

[image: Screenshot from Sanskrit PDF showing Ganesha and Skanda names from pages 28-29]

So, the exact Mantras for Lord Ganesha are like:

> Om Vighnam Tarpayami, Om Vakratundam Tarpayami, Om Lambodaram Tarpayami, Om Ekadantam Tarpayami, Om Vighna Parshadischa Tarpayami etc.

and, those for Lord Karthikeya are like:

> Om Skandam Tarpayami, Om Mahasenam Tarpayami, Om Skanda Parshadischa
>    Tarpayami etc.

Comment: Someone should change the Wikipedia page of ganesha claiming that he is not mentioned in ancient texts.

Comment: Who says that? In Yajnvalkya Smriti too there is large section dedicated to worship of Lord Ganesha. @AnubhavJha

Comment: apparently western indologists think that ganesha is an interpolated diety.

Comment: @Anubhav Jha Lord ganesha is also mentioned in taitterya aryanaka of yajurveda(mahanarayan upanishad).

Comment: Where did you get the translation from? What is the original verse? Can you point me to the verse/translation at [wisdomlib.org/hinduism/ Baudhāyana Dharmasūtra](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/baudh%C4%81yana-dharmas%C5%ABtra)?

Comment: @sv. What do you think about mention of ganesha in Vedas?

Comment: @AnubhavJha Is Baudhayana Dharmasutra ancient text...? This is written much later than Mahabharata..Ganesha is mentioned in Mahabharata... And as per Ramcharitmanas Shiva & Parvati worshiped Ganapati in their marriage ( मुनि अनुशासन गनपति हि पूजेहु शंभु भवानि )..much before the birth of their son Ganesha...so Ganapati is a post and always doesn't mean Parvati's son Ganesha..

Comment: @sv. I have updated the answer.

Comment: @YDS Ganapati is not post. How can you say it is post? Post any proofs if you have any.

Comment: @Rickross headings like edit, update are not needed in the answer. They are unnecessary. You need not write (updated according to user name) for each revision. The answer looks fine without that and gives a feeling of complete answer.

Comment: @TheDestroyer one proof is this choupayi from Ramcharitmanas मुनि अनुशासन गनपति हि पूजेहु शंभु भवानि.. by the way why proof is needed when we know that most of the names are actually posts be it Prajapati, Indra, Saptrishi, Vyasa and so on... Ganapati = Gana + Pati => Head of the Ganas.. this itself conclude that it's a post...

Comment: @sv. It's here:https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/baudh%C4%81yana-dharmas%C5%ABtra/d/doc116423.html

Comment: @Tezz Thanks for the link. Still don't understand how 2.5.9 in the link becomes 2.9.6 in this answer. Maybe two different versions.